# BroadCastReceiver doesn't work when return button

Tags: java, android

I have a BroadCastReceiver and since I don't want it to keep working when the application is uninstalled so I removed the declaration of the receiver  from the manifest . By doing this the receiver will only work when the application is running . That's good so far but I have a little problem which is if the user clicks "home" button on his device to get back to his device's main screen the receiver works in the background , but when he clicks "back" button the receiver will stop working . I want it to work either the user clicked home button or back button.  So how to solve this problem and thanks in advance.
**Note : I'm activating/deactivating the receiver using this code :

```
private BroadCastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new BroadCastReceiver();

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

&& my manifest is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.test"
    android:versionCode="9"
    android:versionName="8.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/danger"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>

        <activity
            android:name="com.aaf.nuclearalert.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
             >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*Update 1 :

```
public void onBackPressed() {

          registerReceiver(myBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION));


        }
```

Comment: onStart of service? Try registering and unregistering in onCreate and onDestroy of Activity

Comment: I think you should unregister your receiver in onStop() method. I think onStop is called when home button is pressed.

Comment: @zkminusck what I want to do is to make it work in the background on both cases , so I want it to work if the user clicks home button or back button

Comment: @FlamePrincessϡ Alright ,I'll try it .

Comment: @FlamePrincessϡ Well It gave the same result

Comment: put a toast message in onDestroy.. And see if it was called?

Comment: @FlamePrincessϡ Toast message shows when I press the back button , but that doesn't make sense because I've already tried to remove the code of onDestroy

Comment: So your app is destroyed. Have you overridden onBackPressed? If yes, show code

Comment: @FlamePrincessϡ No I haven't but I'll try to register the boradCastReceiver on onBackPressed & onDestroy to see what will happen

Comment: @FlamePrincessϡ Just added it (check the update) . Well when I added the back button stopped working so that gave me an Idea which is to make the functionality on back button as same as home button (moving to background instead of destroying) .I'm currently searching for an apply for that , do you know one ??

Comment: Try this: `i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        m_ctx.startActivity(i);` in `onBackPressed`

Comment: @FlamePrincessϡ thanks but sorry for this noob question ,what should I replace "i" with ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70286/discussion-between-flameprincess-and-alphacode).

Comment: @FlamePrincessϡ  it gave me an error "it crashed" . I currently have to go but I'm really thankful for your help , very very thankful . I think I'll create another question regarding the error if I couldn't solve it